# Jquery and Ajax - trigger load with button

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm trying to make a page, where the content is shown using jquery. 
When the user comes to the website, the content is loaded from datanbase. 
I would like to add a button, that would trigger the load of new data from database, but on the same page. How do I do this? :)

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something Like below should help you get started:

```
$(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'path/to/database file',
                success: function() {
                        $("body").append(whatever you want to add);

                }
                });
                });
```